# ImageMagick C# How to Add JPEG EXIF TAGS

Tags: c#, imagemagick, imagemagick.net

Using ImageMagick 8 for .Net in VS2013, Framework 4.6

I am trying to add exif tags to jpeg images,

My Code :

```
var exif = new ExifProfile();
exif.SetValue(ExifTag.Artist, "SM");
exif.SetValue(ExifTag.OwnerName, "ownerexample.com");
exif.SetValue(ExifTag.XPKeywords, "one two three");
```

the problem is that last line throws this:
"exif Value should be an array"

also converting string into string array or byte array won't work,

- am I using right tag (ExifTag.XPKeyWords) for adding Tags to jpeg?
- if I am right then what is the right syntax to add tags to jpeg using ImageMagick?

Comment: Imagemagick cannot save EXIF tags to any image format as far as I know (at least in command line mode). It can only read them. You will need to use EXIFTOOL, for example, to save tags into an image. There is no Imagemagick 8. Current version is 7.0.7.2

Comment: Sorry, my bad , I'm using Magick.NET-Q8-AnyCPU Version 7.0.6.102

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no version 8 of ImageMagick and I suspect that you are using [Magick.NET](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET). You are getting an exception because the `XPKeywords` should be a byte array instead of a string. You should do something like this:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("one two three");
```

You can add the profile to the image with the following code:

```
image.AddProfile(exif);
```

Your operation will decode and encode the image. A tool like exiftool might be better if you just want to change the exif data as @fmw42 suggested.

Comment: I'm using Magick.NET-Q8-AnyCPU Version 7.0.6.102 and
This solution is perfectly working, thank you.